# Ceiling distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

The ceil, or upper integer part ⌈x⌉ of a number x is the smallest integer at least as large as x.

Let X ∼ Exp(λ), and Y = ⌈X⌉.

Identify the distribution of Y and state its mean and variance in terms of λ.

One of my probability homework questions, anyone have any hints or tips? I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be a positive integer. Then 
$$\Pr(Y=y)=\Pr(y-1\lt X\le y)=\int_{y-1}^y \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\,dt.$$

When we evaluate the integral, we obtain $e^{-\lambda(y-1)}-e^{-\lambda y}$.

This can be "simplified" to 
$$(e^{-\lambda})^{y-1}(1-e^{-\lambda}).$$
We leave it to you  to identify the distribution. Once you have done that, mean and variance will only involve things you already know.

**Remark:** If you are already familiar with the "memorylessness" property of the exponential, you can look for a more conceptual solution.