# Exponential and Uniform Distribution Problems

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

### **Questions**

I have the following problems on my probability module:

**Qu1**

Suppose that X is uniformly distributed over $[−3, 3]$.

(a) Find the probability that the first digit of $X$ after the decimal point is $3$.

(b) Find the distribution function of the random variable $|X|$ and use it to identify the
distribution of $|X|$.

(c) Find the density function of the random variable $1/|X|$.

**Qu2**

Let $X$ be a standard exponential random variable, meaning that $X ∼ Exp(1)$. Prove
that the random variable $Y = \lceil X \rceil$ is $Geom(\lambda)$ and find $\lambda$.

---

### **My answers and ideas**

**Qu1**

(a)
$\mathbb P($First digit after deciaml point of X is 3$)$$=\mathbb P(-2.4\lt X\lt -2.2)+\mathbb P(-1.4\lt X\lt -1.2)+\mathbb P(-0.4\lt X\lt -0.2)+\mathbb P(0.2\lt X\lt 0.4)+\mathbb P(1.2\lt X\lt 1.4)+\mathbb P(2.2 \lt X\lt 2.4)=6\mathbb P(0.2\lt X\lt 0.4)=6\frac{0.2}{3-(-3)}=\frac{1}{5}$

Im not 100% sure this is correct be great if someone could check my workings :)

(b)
$|X| \Rightarrow$ $f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3-0},  & \text{if $0\le x \le 3$} \\
0, & \text{o/w}
\end{cases}$

$\Rightarrow F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{3}dt=\frac{1}{3}(x-0)=\frac{x}{3}$

Even less sure with this one :/

(c)
Not confident tackling as I'm unhappy with (b)

**Qu2**

I am clueless on how to approach this, tried drawing various distribution graphs. But they havent seemed to help me :(

---

Be great if anyone could help me by checking solutions and/or helping me with the questions I cannot do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For future reference, it is recommended that you post your questions separately, so Question 1 and Question 2 should be different posts.

One way to conceptualize part (a) is to observe that $Y = 10(X+3)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 60]$, and if the the **tenths digit**, which is first digit after the decimal point of $X$, is $3$, that means the **units** digit of $Y$ is $3$.  This means the set of desired outcomes is $$Y \in [3, 4) \cup [13, 14), \cup \cdots \cup [53, 54).$$  Since this comprises six intervals of unit length, the total length is $6$ out of a total length of $60$, hence the desired probability is $1/10$.

For the second part, you need to rely less on general formulas and reason from first principles.  You cannot blindly integrate the density in the way you have done.

Instead, note that the support of $X$ is on $[-3,3]$, so if $W = |X|$, the support of $W$ is on $[0,3]$.  So we can already establish $\Pr[W < 0] = 0$ and $\Pr[W \le 3] = 1$.  Then for any $w \ge 0$, we must have $$\Pr[W \le w] = \Pr[|X| \le w] = \Pr[-w \le X \le w]  = \Pr[X \le w] - \Pr[X < -w].$$  From here, we can take two approaches.  One is to differentiate with respect to $w$, giving $$f_W(w) = f_X(w) - (-f_X(-w)) = 2f_X(w) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \mathbb 1 (0 \le w \le 3) = \frac{1}{3} \mathbb 1 (0 \le w \le 3),$$ or we can directly substitute the CDF of $X$, which is $$\Pr[X \le x] = \begin{cases}0, & x < -3 \\ (x+3)/6, & -3 \le x \le 3 \\ 1, & x > 3, \end{cases}$$ to obtain $$\begin{align} \Pr[W \le w] &= \begin{cases} 0, & w < 0 \\ (w+3)/6 - (-w+3)/6, & 0 \le w \le 3 \\ 1, & w > 3 \end{cases} \\ &= \begin{cases} 0, & w < 0 \\ w/3, & 0 \le w \le 3 \\ 1, & w > 3. \end{cases} \end{align}$$

For part (c), the random variable $1/|X|$ is simply $1/W$ from the earlier part.  Note that the support of $1/W$ is on $[1/3, \infty)$.  Thus compute $$\Pr[1/W \le w] = \Pr[W \le 1/w]$$ for some $w \in [1/3, \infty)$.

[I addressed Question 2 in a different answer here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3918962/ceiling-of-exponential-distribution/3918998#3918998)

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful! @heropup

Answer (score 2):

For the decimal point to be 3, the number should be between 0.3 and 0.4. Not 0.2 and 0.4.
But this one you can solve with a very intuitive argument: between 0 and 1, each decimal "range" (0-0.1, 0.1-0.2, ...) has the same probability, so the answer should not depend on the fact that the question is about "3". Out of symmetry, the answer should be 0.1.

Your solution for the second part is correct. Again, the probability of $\vert X \vert$ to be in the range $[a,a+\Delta]$ (within $[0,3]$, of course) depends only on $\Delta$ and not the $a$ (it should be $\tfrac{2\Delta}{6}$ since $X$ is uniform), so $\vert X \vert$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.

For the second question, simply calculate the distribution. For natural $t$:

$$\Pr(Y=t)=\Pr(t-1<X<t)=\int\limits_{t-1}^t f_X(u)du =\cdot $$

Can you continue from here and show that the resulting probability looks like the one of Geom?

Comment: Thank you so much that has helped a lot. With the first question I was bit of a donut hehe @YJT

Comment: I understand the logic of what you said for the second question, but I integrateand I cant see the link to Geom?@YJT

Comment: Very rough answer:  after integration you get something like $e^-t-e^{-t-1}$ which can be simplified to $e^-t(1-1/e)$ which looks like the geometric $p^t (1-p)$ with $p=1/e$

Comment: Omg thanks I did get that after integrating but i couldnt see the link thanks a lot mate! @YJT